# Can you add a physical computer (laptop) to a vm domain controller which sits on a host PC?

Tags: virtualbox, dns, vmware, windows-server-2016

I saw this question but I'll provide a bit more description in bullet point.  I created various virtual machines (2 to be exact) on my host PC - one a Server 2016 and another one Windows 10.  Server 2016 acts as a domain controller, and was able to create several user accounts.  I joined the virtual Windows 10 on the domain successfully and able to log in through created user accounts.  My question is, can you join another physical computer (in this case a laptop - Macbook Pro) to this virtualized domain controller?

Set up that sits on my Windows 10 host PC:

- Virtualbox

  - Windows Server 2016

    - 2 Network adapters (Internal and external)

      - NAT (external) - has home router's gateway access.
      - Internal (provides internet access to VMs connected to domain)
  - Windows 10

    - 1 Internal adapter

I am able to connect the Win 10 vm to the server 2016 via DHCP and gain access to the internet.  Both machines work perfect.

My main question is, is it even possible to allow other external devices (I'm operating all of this on my home network) such as a laptop or other computers to the virtual domain created that sits on a host pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.  As long as the physical machine can reach the network the domain controller is on, it can join it.  This would mean setting the network in VirtualBox to bridged.  Then any machine on your LAN can communicate with and/or join the domain.  There are other networking methods, as well.  You can assign a physical network adapter to the server, which is on the LAN, as well.

Comment: This of course would mean that, if you were to lose the VM, you wouldn't be able to log into that domain-connected account without a local account that already exists.  **You should obviously avoid connecting the host computer to the domain.**

Comment: Thanks for the help! I joined the macbook finally!

Comment: @RobertoLopez Awesome.  If that worked for you.  Mark it up and accept it, so people know that answer worked!

Comment: Thank you Keltari,I wanted to include this but I was just short on time at that moment.  So, I was able to join my physical MacBook Pro laptop by assigning a static IP of the internal NIC of the domain computer, and logging on with other users' account was also a success.  However, I was not able to get access to the internet.  I don't know if its a firewall issue, since the other windows 10 VM is also connected to the Windows Server and has the same DNS address and gateway as my MAC and this one (windows 10) does have internet connectivity.  Any suggestions as to what this might be?